# Can I use Node to build a payment gateway software?

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway

I know it is a subjective question, but the reason I ask this question is because

1. Node.js is not good with heavy computational task
2. Node.js has some issue with memory leak.

By having the problems above, would node be a good use case to build a payment gateway software?

I'm very comfortable with node, but there are many people said that its better to use other language like golang or scala for this type of systems.

Let me know what you guys think about, whether I should use Node or other languages.

Comment: "not good" with "heavy ... task" and "issues" with "memory leak" is not specific enough. Can you rephrase this? What is "heavy"? What does "issue with memory leak" mean?

Comment: Why the sudden downvote, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I assume someone thinks nodejs is good in heavy computational tasks and has no issues with memory leaks. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @sinusGob You didn't do anything wrong, it's just that possible answers to this question are too much opinion based. :) The question will be likely closed soon for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, node.js would be perfectly fine for payment gateway software.  An appropriate design using clustering or off-loading computation tasks to child processes could easily help optimize heavy computational tasks.

And, node.js is being used by many heavy traffic commercial sites without memory leak issues.  Memory leaks are an issue with faulty software design, not with the platform.

Further, the very nature of payment gateway software (being the middleman in a transaction between two other networking endpoints) is very well set up for the node.js async design that handles lots of in-flight transactions very efficiently.

As with pretty much any major back-end system these days, you just have to design your app to work the way the platform performs best and you could probably use any of the systems you mention just fine.